# How to display post with two custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type - Poems.
And I create a two taxonomy - Cities and Authors.
When I clicked on "Paris" menu item - I need to displayed all Authors and his  list of poems in that city.
How to do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely want to take a look at the [Codex entry for WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). That gives you all the information you could want on creating custom WordPress queries. Including taxonomy arguments.

You'd want to pass to tax query arguments using the AND relation. Something along the lines of this example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'city',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'london',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'dickens',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Edit: 10/30/17 per comment below**

If you were saving your author's as post meta you could order by that. But if your author is also a taxonomy it gets a little trickier since there isn't a good way to order by a taxonomy. See this [related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy/).

Instead we could get all of our author taxonomy terms using `get_terms`.

```
$authors = get_terms( 'author', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

That gives us all author terms that have at least one post assigned to them.

Now that we have the terms we could run through each author and run a query to get the poems for that author in that city. Like so:

```
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'poem',
        'tax_query' => array(
            relation => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'london',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'author',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $author->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );    

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            // Put your post markup here

        endwhile;

    endif; wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: In this example the terms are strictly indicated but i want to display all posts of each authors with all cities taxanomy (London,Paris,Madrid etc)

Comment: OK. I think I follow. Assuming all Poems have authors I'll update the answer  to get all of the Poems for a particular city, ordered by author.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not good with coding you can use free Content Views plugin, and combine that yyou have to combine. I started like this.